# Are on-prem Windows Virtual Desktop servers still a thing?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, vdi

My supervisor wants me to look into a virtual Windows 10/11 desktop solution leveraging our on-prem VMware cluster. Luckily, our cluster hardware has plenty of CPU/RAM/storage to accomplish the scope of the solution. The issue I'm running into is finding tutorials on how to set this up using Windows Server 2022-era products. All the solutions I can find seem to require an Azure tenant.
I would have no issues recommending an Azure-integrated solution, except for the kicker: My company's Azure tenant is managed by a non-US corporation, to which we have no administrative access and getting an Azure VDI solution in place is so convoluted as to be effectively impossible.
I know Windows Virtual Desktop is old tech and I totally understand why Microsoft is pushing Azure cloud services instead of on-prem solutions, but my situation dictates that I come up with an on-prem solution that will have the potential to last the next 3-5 years without Microsoft killing it with EoL support and security update cancellations.

My question is two-fold:

1. Is Microsoft Virtual Desktop still a thing, and if so, where can I find some tutorials (preferable video-based, like YouTube) on setting it up?
2. Is an on-prem, Windows-based VDI solution viable (even if you wouldn't recommend it over Azure, Horizon VDI, or Citrix) for the next 3-5 years (until my company gets with the times and moves to the cloud)?

Comment: This doc is nicely done to explain some step. It's a third part vendor doc, so expect some sale speech from them, but as I'am reading it it seem clean to date. https://www.vallalkozzdigitalisan.hu/dl/partners/579/dokumentum_4700_1.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Microsoft Virtual Desktop still a thing?

Yes

> Is an on-prem, Windows-based VDI solution viable?

Yes

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-deploy-infrastructure